# How do I improve the python function for boxcox transformation?

Tags: python, function, normal-distribution

I created a function giving a fair evaluation of lambda coefficient for a given series/list of data, however it takes lot of time when the input has a long size, is there some tips to speed it up ?

This is my code:

```
from scipy.stats import norm, pearsonr

def get_lambda_coef(series):
    x=[series[i] for i in range(len(series))]
    for i in range(len(x)-1):
        for j in range(len(x)-1):
            if x[j]>=x[j+1]:
                z=x[j]
                x[j]=x[j+1]
                x[j+1]=z
    i=[j for j in range(1,len(x)+1)]
    f=[(i[j]-0.375)/(len(x)+0.25) for j in range(len(x))]
    u=[norm.ppf(f[i]) for i in range(len(x))]
        
    lambda_coef=0
    width=3
    step=width/6
    k=lambda_coef-width
    iteration=1
    while iteration<=15:
        r_vector=[]
        lambda_vect=[]
        while k<=lambda_coef+width:
            if k==0:
                y=[np.log(i) for i in x]
            else:
                y=[(i**k-1)/k for i in x]
            r_vector.append(pearsonr(y, u)[0])
            k+=step
        k=lambda_coef-width
        while k<=lambda_coef+width:
            lambda_vect.append(k)
            k+=step
        lambda_coef=lambda_vect[r_vector.index(max(r_vector))]
        width/=2
        step/=3
        k=lambda_coef-width
        iteration+=1
    normalized = [(x**lambda_coef - 1)/lambda_coef for x in series]
    return (normalized, lambda_coef)
```

Any help from your side will be highly appreciated (I upvote all answers).

Thank you !

Comment: `x=[series[i] for i in range(len(series))]` Why would you do this?! Same for `[j for j in range(1,len(x)+1)]` - if you *really* want to make a list, `list(range(1, x+1))` would do. Also also, just use [out-of-the box solution](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.boxcox.html)...

Comment: `boxcox_normmax` from the same library provides an option to maximize `pearsonr` (default) instead of log-likelihood (also provided as an option).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I can see that you are using nested loops. The Time complexity of the below part is

`O(n**2)`

instead you can sort it

You can replace this code with `sorted()` function:

```
x=[series[i] for i in range(len(series))]
for i in range(len(x)-1):
        for j in range(len(x)-1):
            if x[j]>=x[j+1]:
                z=x[j]
                x[j]=x[j+1]
                x[j+1]=z
```

The time complexity for sorted is `O(NlogN)`

```
x=sorted(series)
```

Comment: Great ! I use this and see its performance, please take a look at the remaining part as well

Comment: @KhaledDELLAL you can get rid of nested while loops. They can cause performance issues